# What do these messages in the Qmail maillog indicate?

Tags: email

There seems to be an endless supply of messages in the Qmail maillog for a single address.  Can anyone shed some light on why this might be and whether it is a problem?  To me it looks like either spam or some sort of unhandled problem.  It strikes me as unusual that the 'from=' field is blank.  This is on a VPS using Plesk in case that's important.

```
Jun 30 15:10:17 vps-1001108-595 qmail-remote-handlers[23593]: to=cielofidelidade@cartoes.com
Jun 30 15:10:17 vps-1001108-595 qmail-remote-handlers[23586]: from=
Jun 30 15:10:17 vps-1001108-595 qmail-remote-handlers[23586]: to=cielofidelidade@cartoes.com
Jun 30 15:10:17 vps-1001108-595 qmail-remote-handlers[23585]: from=
Jun 30 15:10:17 vps-1001108-595 qmail-remote-handlers[23585]: to=cielofidelidade@cartoes.com
Jun 30 15:10:17 vps-1001108-595 qmail-remote-handlers[23584]: from=
Jun 30 15:10:17 vps-1001108-595 qmail-remote-handlers[23584]: to=cielofidelidade@cartoes.com
Jun 30 15:10:17 vps-1001108-595 qmail-remote-handlers[23583]: from=
Jun 30 15:10:17 vps-1001108-595 qmail-remote-handlers[23583]: to=cielofidelidade@cartoes.com
Jun 30 15:10:17 vps-1001108-595 qmail-remote-handlers[23600]: from=
Jun 30 15:10:17 vps-1001108-595 qmail-remote-handlers[23600]: to=cielofidelidade@cartoes.com
Jun 30 15:10:17 vps-1001108-595 qmail-remote-handlers[23599]: from=
Jun 30 15:10:17 vps-1001108-595 qmail-remote-handlers[23599]: to=cielofidelidade@cartoes.com
```

**EDIT**
Here's a sample of one of the emails:

```
Received: (qmail 5603 invoked for bounce); 29 Jun 2011 07:46:31 +0100
Date: 29 Jun 2011 07:46:31 +0100
From: MAILER-DAEMON@vps-1001108-595.cp.something.com
To: cielofidelidade@cartoes.com
Subject: failure notice

Hi. This is the qmail-send program at vps-1001108-595.cp.something.com.
I'm afraid I wasn't able to deliver your message to the following addresses.
This is a permanent error; I've given up. Sorry it didn't work out.

<etspetroni@zipmail.com.br>:
200.147.36.13 does not like recipient.
Remote host said: 450 4.7.1 Client host rejected: cannot find your hostname, [XX.XXX.XXX.XXX]
Giving up on 200.147.36.13.
I'm not going to try again; this message has been in the queue too long.

--- Below this line is a copy of the message.

Return-Path: <cielofidelidade@cartoes.com>
Received: (qmail 15585 invoked by uid 48); 22 Jun 2011 07:38:26 +0100
Date: 22 Jun 2011 07:38:26 +0100
Message-ID: <20110622063826.15583.qmail@vps-1001108-595.cp.something.com>
To: etspetroni@zipmail.com.br
Subject: Cadastre-se e Concorra ? um Carro!
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
From: Cielo Fidelidade <cielofidelidade@cartoes.com>


<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
... <body text removed>
<html>
```

If I understand this correctly, this is saying that an email sent by my server, from address cielofidelidade@cartoes.com, could not be delivered.  However, cielofidelidade@cartoes.com is not a valid email address on my server, so how can email be sent from this address on my server?  I have tested whether my server is acting as an open relay, and it isn't.  So how else could this be happening?  I am getting thousands of these every day.  What can I do to prevent it?

Comment: If that is reporting the envelope sender/recipient addresses, then a blank from line is usually indicative of the NULL sender, meaning it's probably a bounced message, which might be an indication that the recipient sent (or was spoofed to have sent) a bunch of undeliverable mail. I think you need to look at more logs before anything can be determined about your situation with any confidence, though.

Comment: It looks to me like some sort of loop, though. What exactly is qmail-remote-handlers?

Comment: Yeah I thought it might be some bad config on the server which is just looping a bounced mail internally.  I don't know what qmail-remote-handlers is, as far as I know, qmail-remote just handles the delivery of remote mail.

Comment: I've never seen qmail-remote in my use of qmail over the years. But there are many qmail add-ons that I'm not familiar with. I don't think qmail-remote-handlers is part of the core system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to what Flimzy has already pointed out as likely NDRs, this situation may be indicative of an ongoing backscatter attack/outbreak taking place.

Answer (score 1):

We had many of these messages in the mail.info log, on our dedicated server (Plesk).

Just before this the SMTP relay was compromised and was used to send out a bit of SPAM.
After changing users password and enabling RBL in plesk, these type of messages would still keep displaying in the log.

We just cleared qmails queue:
Seems to have stop the messages.

http://dragos.fedorovici.com/plesk-clear-qmail-queue/